# How exactly can a selected field or item from the TControlList be deleted?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.4.2

I'm new to using component `TControlList`. Can someone help with this.

How exactly can a selected field or item from the `TControlList` be deleted for example?

I'm filling the items to `TControlList` from `SQLLite` database like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ControlList1BeforeDrawItem(AIndex: Integer; ACanvas: TCanvas;
  ARect: TRect; AState: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  dm.fdmedcin.RecNo := AIndex+1;
  lbl5.Caption := 'Spc:' +TStringField( dm.fdmedcin.FieldByName('Spc_doc') ).AsString ;

.........

procedure TDM.fdmedcinAfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  form1.ControlList1.ItemCount := fdmedcin.RecordCount;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You get the selected item with `TControlList.ItemIndex`.

One solution could be that you create a method that deletes the entry in your `fdmedcin` and re-set the `TControlList.ItemCount` again like in your example.

```
form1.ControlList1.ItemCount := fdmedcin.RecordCount;
```

I don't know your exact code but it could look like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Delete;
begin
  dm.fdmedcin.RecNo := ControlList1.ItemIndex + 1; // seems like you add one in your OnBeforeDrawItem too
  dm.fdmedcin.Delete;
  ControlList1.ItemCount := fdmedcin.RecordCount;
end;
```

In other words: you have to match the `TControlList.ItemIndex` with your DataSet/whatever index.

I made a simple example with a `TList<T>` while `T` is an `integer`:

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    BFill: TButton;
    ControlList1: TControlList;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    BDelete: TButton;
    MSQuery1: TMSQuery;
    procedure BFillClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ControlList1BeforeDrawItem(AIndex: Integer; ACanvas: TCanvas; ARect: TRect; AState: TOwnerDrawState);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FList: TList<integer>;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.BDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FList.Delete(ControlList1.ItemIndex);
  ControlList1.ItemCount := FList.Count;
end;

procedure TForm2.BFillClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ControlList1.ItemCount := FList.Count;
end;

procedure TForm2.ControlList1BeforeDrawItem(AIndex: Integer; ACanvas: TCanvas; ARect: TRect; AState: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(FList[AIndex]);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  FList := TList<integer>.Create;
  for i := 0 to 9 do
    FList.Add(i);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FList.Free;
end;
```

Comment: the first method worked like a charm thank s a lot i did not have to try the second one , I Can't Thank You Enough
can some upvote the answer cause i can't